# ABP IdentityServer Client Management

Tags: abp

Where can I find the Client management application service for ABP?
I am currently using V3.2, but I can't find the implementation anywhere on GitHub.

According to the documentation: https://docs.abp.io/en/commercial/3.2/modules/identity-server there should be a class `ApiResourceAppService` but that doesn't seem to exist either and the ClientAppService seems to be missing even from the documentation.

I would like to add client management to my application and therefor I want to overwrite the ABP implementation and add my custom logic there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documents you have shared is **commercial** documentation.

[IdentityServer](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/tree/dev/modules/identityserver/src) module containtains the domain logic. There is also a commercial module named [IdentityServer UI](https://commercial.abp.io/modules/Volo.Identityserver.Ui) which contains the application service implementations and the UI of identity server.

If you already own commercial license, you can check [support](https://support.abp.io/) for how to override existing modules. Otherwise, you need to introduce and implement the whole identityserver UI logic yourself.

You can also check [abp free and commercial modules comparison](https://docs.abp.io/en/commercial/latest/abp-framework-vs-abp-commercial#modules).